# VSI powerState stays ''HALTED' when I create by dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag: true

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used softlayer api to create VSI. And I met a problem when 'dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag' is true for dedicated VSI.

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.json
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
                "globalIdentifier": "2aae2a36-76f3-4d2f-9881-e86fa15b040b"
            },
            "datacenter": {
                "name": "lon02"
            },
            "dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag": true,
            "domain": "softlayer.com",
            "hostname": "redis--031242-787",
            "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
            "localDiskFlag": false,
            "maxMemory": 8192,
            "networkComponents": [
                {
                    "maxSpeed": 100
                }
            ],
            "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                "networkVlan": {
                    "id": 1292651,
                    "networkSpace": "PRIVATE"
                }
            },
            "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": true,
            "startCpus": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

The VSI's trasaction is stuck with `CLOUD_PROVISION_SETUP` transaction and then powerState is still `HALTED` for long time.

Is it the virtual guest template incorrect? Or is something else the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Nope the template is fine otherwise the order would never had started the provision, the issue is at provisioning time, it may due to many reasons (e.g. the private network that you picked out does not have enough room or the datacenter is full), anyway in those cases a Softlayer Employee must review the provisioning process and fix it if he cannot do it he will contact you in order to let you know, So you can wait until the employee solve the problem or you can open a ticket and ask why you order is stuck.